# Wi-Fi not working only on Ubuntu computer?

Tags: 12.04, wireless, internet-connection

The Wi-Fi at our house does not work on my Asus notebook running Ubuntu 12.04. It works fine on all other devices except this one. Internet worked fine before I had Ubuntu and I had Windows 7, but we also had a different ISP and place. My roommate's Windows 7 notebook and netbook both work fine with the internet and so do all of our phones and iPods. I do not know what is wrong because it works fine EVERYWHERE else, but when I am connected to my own router at my house it is either EXTREMELY slow or it just loads and loads and loads. I have all of the correct drivers and all that so why is it just this one connection that is a problem. I do not know if this matters but the ISP is Comcast and so is the Modem/wireless-router.

Any help is much appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Does your notebook have a Ethernet connection? If so, can you try that to see how it works? (Just testing through-put, to see if the ISP is bottlenecking because of the OS. It shouldn't matter, but you never know.)

What about the security of the router, is it open, WEP, or WPA? What's the model number of it? What's the model of your laptop?

Comment: To get output from user you must use comment not answers.

Comment: I'm not at home so I can't give you the model of the router, but the security is WPA and the laptop is an Asus K53E-RIN5. I should be back home by 7 at the very latest, so please check back then. Thank you.

Comment: Hey the router is an Arris Model: TG862G/CT and the ISP is comcast

Answer (score 0):

The cause could be bug #1003842. Try disabling the NetworkManager-controlled dnsmasq instance.  With root privileges edit `NetworkManager.conf`.

```
gksudo gedit /etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf
```

comment out the line

```
dns=dnsmasq
```

such that it looks like

```
#dns=dnsmasq
```

Then

```
stop network-manager
killall dnsmasq
start network-manager
```

If this doesn't help then, of course, you should revert the change to `NetworkManager.conf` and restart network-manager again.